# Why didn't Murdock notice that Fisk wasn't lying when he talked about improving the city?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

I'm only up to *Daredevil* S01E09 so far and Murdock just went to the art gallery to meet with Fisk's Girlfriend. But if I understand this correctly, Fisk genuinely wants to fix the city. So when Murdock was talking to Fisk, why didn't he seem to note that Fisk was telling the truth when he talked about improving the city?

Comment: Even if he did notice, would it have changed anything? Matt fought Fisk because Fisk was funding organized crime, committing murder, and paying thugs to intimidate the poor into leaving their homes. It didn't matter to Matt what Fisk's end goal was; he was a person committing evil acts and needed to be stopped. A big part of the moral tension in the show is that Matt doesn't believe that the end justifies the means...except he kinda does, sometimes, usually when they're his end and his means. We see this again in Season 2.

Comment: @Torisuda It would still make a difference. Matt currently seems to be going through a moral dilemma of whether or not to kill Fisk, and if he realized that Fisk wanted the same thing he did, albeit in a (to him) twisted way, it should have been part of the dilemma.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fisk wasn't lying, so there's no reason to make note of him noticing that Fisk wasn't lying. People that believe what they're doing is right can be dangerous. We have every reason to believe that Matt takes Fisk's plans seriously.

The idea that Fisk believes he is right, as does Matt, are part of the theme throughout the series. Here's an interaction between Matt and Foggy in episode 10:

> **Matt**: We don't live in a world that's fair. We live in this one. And I'm doing everything I can to make it a better place.
>   **Foggy**: "A better place." That kind of sounds like what Fisk keeps saying.

Both characters believe they're doing what's right. Foggy here was making that rather explicit for us. Both are violent men. Matt is trying to find out what kind of man he is, and what his limits are. It's also the nature of many of his talks with the Catholic priest.

Is he like Fisk, or is he really a better angel with the devil in him?

Comment: Translation: the concept of "improving the city" is relative.

Comment: Ouch: _People that believe what they're doing is right can be dangerous_... So most people most of the time. Good point for the show.